# how to showing the modal on the front?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-modal

Show the modal on the front. When i am increasing the `margin-top` the modal div is hiding behind the another div what should i do. As i stuck in this problem.

And css code is:

```css
.vertical-alignment-helper {
  display:table;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  pointer-events:none;
}

.vertical-align-center {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
  pointer-events:none;
}

.modal-content {
  border: .5px solid rgba(0,0,0,.2) !important;
  border-radius: 1px !important;
  border-color: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.64) !important;
  width:inherit;
  height:inherit;
  margin: 0 auto;
  pointer-events:all;
}

.close {
  margin-top: -20px !important;
  margin-right: -10px !important;
}

.close:hover{
  background-color:none !important;
}
```

here is my HTML Code

```
<li class="pull-right"><a href="#" class="getmap button btn-small yellow-bg white-color" role="button" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal" onclick="getmap()">GET DIRECTIONS</a></li>





            <div class="modal" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
<div class="vertical-alignment-helper">
    <div class="modal-dialog vertical-align-center">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span><span class="sr-only">Close</span>

                </button>
                 <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Modal title</h4>

            </div>
            <div class="modal-body row">
            <div class="col-md-3">
             <div class="form-group">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="MinVal">
</div>
<div class="form-group">    
     <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="MaxVal">   
</div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-9" id="mymap" style="width: 400px; height: 200px">



            </div>

        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

[image]

Comment: I dont see any z-index, did you try it ?

Comment: z-index is not working . i tried that.

Comment: might be i am using z-index at wrong place . where do i set that?

Comment: z-index worker for position: absolute/relative/fixed elements

Comment: you have not given us enough code to go on and test it out please supply a jsfiddle with the problem. I would say it could be a z-index problem. it depends on how you are applying your z-index

Comment: added ur html code

Comment: i just added my html code can you please help me out...

Answer (score 0):

Give the maximum z-index value

```
.modal{z-index:99999;}
```

Answer (score 0):

**z-index** for a relative div has nothing to do with the z-index of an absolutely or fixed div.

```
.modal-content {
      position:absolute;
      z-index:9999999;
    }
```

Comment: not working . on putting your code modal doesn't appear only shows black screen

Comment: make check if other element given z-index:9999999999